# How can I append a node to the beginning of a div in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently appending a node to the end of a div to dynamically add to a div but I am looking to append it to the beginning rather than the end of the div.

my current code looks like this:

```
var para=document.createElement('div');

var node=document.createTextNode('this is new');
para.appendChild(node);

var element=document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);


<div id="div1">
<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

How can I append to the beginning of the div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) with the parent's [firstChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.firstChild) as the reference element:

```
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.insertBefore(para, element.firstChild);
```

Comment: @Justin, in that case, `firstChild` will be `null`, and `insertBefore()` will proceed to append the new element to the end of the parent (which is the same as the beginning, since it is empty).

Answer (score 2):

Look into jQuery (http://www.jquery.com) because it'll make your life just so much easier. Other libraries exist, but jQuery is the most popular.

Your code with jQuery:

```
$("<div/>").append("this is new").appendTo($("#div1"))
```

And for prepending:

```
$("<div/>").prepend("this is new").prependTo($("#div1"))
```

Comment: This helped me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`element.insertBefore(para, element.firstChild )`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.insertBefore

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure but you can do something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
dv=document.createElement('div1');
txt=document.createTextNode('this is new');
dv.appendChild(txt);
document.getElementById('div1').appendChild(dv);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript insertBefore() method. when you are adding to the dom.